# How to schedule audio to play when user win or lose a game in jQuery browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

***Functionality:***

Audio is played in main game page and in other pages, hence when user wins the game, there is a Game Win notification sound before reverting back to the main audio when the game page changes to game congratulation page. While, when user loses the game, there will be a Game lost notification sound before reverting back to the main audio when the game page changes to the GameOver page.

***What has been done:***

I have managed to create the main audio and it is playing for all pages.

***Issue:***

I am unable to set the

1.) GameWin notification sound

2.) GameLost notification sound

to play when the user either win or lose the game during the page transition. The main audio is still playing.

Hence, how am I able set the notification audio to play when the user either win or lose the game during the page transition from the game page to either the game win page or the game lose page.

I have attached the code for perusal..please help.

```js
function initiateGameTimer() {
  CounterInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    timer = timer - 1;
    $('#GameTime').html(timer);
    console.log(timer);
    // Gamce condition check when timer =0: position of the star < or > 2308(bottom page limit)
    if (timer == 0) {
      clearInterval(CounterInterval);
      if (x >= 1440) {
        $("#GamePage").hide();
        $("#Congratulations").show();
      } else if (x < 1440) {
        console.log("fail");
        $("#GamePage").hide();
        $("#GameOver").show();
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=1;">

  <div id="jquery_jplayer_4" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
  <audio src="lib/Elements/happy.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>

</div>

<div id="Congratulations" style="display:none; width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=2;">
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_5" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
  <audio src="lib/Elements/audioCongratulations.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
</div>

<div id="GameOver" style="display:none; left:0; top:0; width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=2; ">
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_6" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
  <audio src="lib/Elements/audiogameOver.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
  <input id="OK" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Ok.png" onclick="RevertPage()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Look there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement it might be easier to achieve what you want

Comment: You could simply call `play()` on the audio element when required.

Comment: The <audio>-tag supports a bunch of events, documented for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Or google "html5 audio events"

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. found  way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It can be done via this way:

```js
function initiateGameTimer() {
  CounterInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    timer = timer - 1;
    $('#GameTime').html(timer);
    console.log(timer);
    // Gamce condition check when timer =0: position of the star < or > 2308(bottom page limit)
    if (timer == 0) {
      clearInterval(CounterInterval);
      if (x >= 1440) {
        var audioWon = document.getElementById("GameWon");
        audioWon.play();
        $("#GamePage").hide();
        $("#Congratulations").show();
      } else if (x < 1440) {
        console.log("fail");
        var audioLose = document.getElementById("GameLose");
        audioLose.play();
        $("#GamePage").hide();
        $("#GameOver").show();
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="Congratulations" style="display:none; width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=2;">
  <audio id="GameWon" src="lib/Elements/GameCompleted.mp3">Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_5" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
</div>

<div id="GameOver" style="display:none; left:0; top:0; width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=2; ">
  <audio id="GameLose" src="lib/Elements/GameFail.mp3">Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_6" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
  <input id="OK" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Ok.png" onclick="RevertPage()" />
</div>
```

I have added an extra `<audio>` tag  within each of the  for GameWon and GameOver, while I set to the assign a variable to each of the `<audio>` tag id and call the method `play()` to play the audio when the respective div id is called.